# Configuring Django Production Settings and Content Security Policy

Tags: django, security, heroku

I'm trying to configure my site to pass the tests at:

- https://observatory.mozilla.org
- https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/

I've been looking at this [blog post](http://andrearobertson.com/blog/2018/05/19/django-example-setting-up-http-security/). I'm using the D[jango app called django-csp](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to implement this. My Django settings in production are as follows:

```
# Content Security Policy
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'none'", )
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'", "fonts.googleapis.com", "'sha256-/3kWSXHts8LrwfemLzY9W0tOv5I4eLIhrf0pT8cU0WI='")
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'", )
CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'",)
CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'", "fonts.gstatic.com")
CSP_CONNECT_SRC = ("'self'", )
CSP_OBJECT_SRC = ("'none'", )
CSP_BASE_URI = ("'none'", )
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'", 'https://example.com/', 'https://example.com/')
CSP_FORM_ACTION = ("'self'", )
CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN = ('script-src',)

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
```

Yet, when I run the aforementioned tests I fail even though I have the above setup. Moreover, in Chrome dev tools I receive no errors, which is great.

[image]

Anyone have advice on this please?
Thanks

**Update:**

I'm deploying the app via Heroku. When I test the appname.herokuapp.com url with Mozilla Observatory, I pass all the tests.

It seems that when I forward the domain appname.herokuapp.com to mywebsite.com, some settings are skipped? I failed the tests with mywebsite.com

I have added the CNAME www to be the value of the custom Heroku DNS.

Comment: Are you using the django-csp library mentioned there? Those settings won't do anything on their own.

Comment: Yes, I am. I will edit the post to mention that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the issue arises when I forward the heroku domain to my websites domain. It doesn't appear to be a Django settings issue. More like a DNS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, my issue was in the way I had configured my DNS settings. I kept my Django prodution settings as is (see above).

I added a custom domain in my Heroku settings and used the auto-generated server name in my CNAME settings in Cloudflare.

Then I ran a check in Mozilla Observatory and passed the tests.